# Android - Terminate process while in another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, process

I'm having my main activity starting another activity which will render the UI. When I try to stop the process from Eclipse while in the second activity, the process just instantly gets restarted! I have to press "Back" once before I can manually stop the process without it being restarted

What am I missing?

Main activity:

```
package org.test;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class main extends ActivityGroup {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Second activity:

```
package org.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class ScreenMain extends Activity {
    private GridView mGridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: ActivityManager is deprecated, unless you are targeting 1.5 or below you should be using Fragment and FragmentManager. Also the implementation you have shown has no reaosn to use ActivityManager.

Comment: I think you have to read the behaviour of ActivityGroup(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html#ActivityGroup()). May be it will be helpful to you..